# Spring/SpringBoot Administration panel like Django Admin

Tags: django, spring, spring-boot

I have a generic question about Spring-SpringBoot.

I'm familiar with Django. Using Django it's possible to integrate the Administration panel to manage the entities and other functions.

Using Spring/Spring boot is there the same concept? So, It's possible to have a configurable Administration panel to have the CRUD operations on your entities?